# DataContract not included on client side

Tags: c#, wcf

I have very simple, following issue. I defined two classes marked by DataContract attribute as follows:

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    string Surname { get; set; }

    string ConfidentialName { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Employee : Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

and service contract exposes precisely one method:

```
[OperationContract]
void GetEmployee(Person employee);
```

When client consumes service there is no definition of Employee class. Is that caused because Employee is never used? Should not it be included anyway in order to use if for instance if I wanted to pass Employee object to GetEmployee method?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this on the server side

```
      <add type="Person, MyAssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=null">
        <knownType type="Employee, MyAssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      </add>


  </declaredTypes>
</dataContractSerializer>
```